# Unity C# - Time.time & time.deltatime

Tags: c#

What are the differences between these two floats, when and how to use them? I checked the Unity Scripting API and I still don't understand them that much, so I came here to ask about it.

Referenced docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html

Comment: When you ask a question like that, please provide links to the docs you are referencing (like: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html). I know nothing about Unity, but `time` appears (from the docs) like the time since the game started (how long has the player been playing).  The `deltaTime` property _provides the time between the current and previous frame_, i.e., how long each frame needs to be composed and displayed. The `time` property will monotonically increase, while `deltaTime` will remain reasonably constant within a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically,

the Time.time is the time that has passed since the beginning of the cycle, this can be used to get the time since the game started.

Time.deltatime is the time that has passed to complete the last frame, this should be used to implement a timer for an activity in the game.

[reference 1]https://forum.unity.com/threads/time-time-or-time-deltatime.495010/

[reference 2]https://answers.unity.com/questions/1438383/the-difference-between-timetime-and-timedeltatime.html